# How do I get angle brackets to display properly in C++ code within markdown-it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, markdown-it

I'm truing to use markdown-it.js with nodejs to render a markdown page containing some c++ code.

This is the javascript code, which transforms everything in the body tag:

```js
var markdownjs = require('markdown-it')({ html: true });
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
bodyHTML = body.innerHTML;
bodyHTML = markdownjs.render(bodyHTML);
body.innerHTML = bodyHTML
```

This is the markdown html document:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Hello Javascript</title>

# Hello Javascript

- test1

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }
`` `

<script src="bundle.js" ></script>
````

Everything is rendering as I expect, except that in the c++ code the stream/shift operators are rendered as &lt ;

Answer (score 0):

Consider escaping the angle brackets with their respective conterparts

- `&lt;` for `<`
- `&gt;` for `>`

````
    ```cpp
        #include <iostream>

        int main(int argc, char * argv[])
        {
            std::cout &lt;&lt; "Hello World" &lt;&lt; std::endl;
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that does not work either. Interestingly <iostream> is working fine, and has 2 angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

OK figured out what it was.
For whatever reason markdown-it was rendering:
**<** as **&amp ;lt;** and **>** as **&amp ;gt;**
I had to add some additional transformation to replace **& amp;** with **&**.

NOTE: In the above there is no space between & and amp, I put that in, because & + amp + ; is turning into &, and i'm not sure how to escape it.